# URL config confusing

Tags: django, url

I have problem with these URLs

```
 (r'^(?P<jobtype>[\w|\W]+)/$', 'index'),  
 (r'^profile/$','profile'),     
 (r'^profile/addJob/$', 'addJob'),
 (r'^profile/editjob/(?P<jobid>.*)/$', 'editJob')
```

The first pass to "index" function, second will pass to "profile" function, the third and fourth should pass to "addJob" and "editJob" function, but they both use the first url-configuration and pass to "index" function, which give me errors, what should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

the first regex have already matched all urls.

```
 (r'^profile/$','profile'),     
 (r'^profile/addJob/$', 'addJob'),
 (r'^profile/editjob/(?P<jobid>.*)/$', 'editJob')
 (r'^(?P<jobtype>[\w|\W]+)/$', 'index'),
```

Comment: it doen't help, django will still use (r'^(?P<jobtype>[\w|\W]+)/$', 'index') to all rest of URLs

Comment: it still cathc (r'^(?P<jobtype>[\w|\W]+)/$', 'index'),  even i put in the last of it

Comment: It will catch all of your urls since you've specified a regex that catches any word. `(r'^(?P<jobtype>[\w|\W]+)/$', 'index')` == `(r'^profile/$','profile'),`.

Comment: what should i do to seperate them? how to make a url with parameter that points to the index page?